# Can I use Git for source control and still be SOX compliant?

Tags: svn, git, sox

I'd like to consider migrating from Subversion to Git for my source control but my company is bound by SOX compliance.

Has anyone successfully implemented Git in a SOX compliant environment and if so could you elaborate on any of the potential pitfalls?

Thanks

Paul

Comment: What makes Subversion SOX compliant?

Comment: You might find this question gets good answers over at http://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Only your organisation and its processes can be SOX-compliant. If you're asking whether Git can be used to implement a version control/software development process which is SOX-compliant, you should clarify your question and provide links/information to the aspects of compliance (I assume you're referring to security/access control) which you're interested in instituting, if possible.

That having been said, since Git operates using a secure protocol (SSH), gives you a high degree of confidence in the integrity of a repo's contents (due to commit and tree SHA1 hashes), and can implement granular access controls (using e.g. [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)), the answer to your question is most likely ‘yes’

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've been told there could be security issues with backup for internal Git repositories so I wondered if there was anyone out there who is actually using Git in a SOX compliant company.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the security issues, maybe amend your original question with them?

Answer (score 2):

There are products on the market (i.e. http://GitEnterprise.com) that helps in providing additional audit-trail capabilities. Even though those are not enough for producing a fully compliant SOX report, it provides the minimal ICT Security requirements needed by Companies that requires SOX compliance (i.e. Finance, Banks, Industries working on payments).

See https://gitent-scm.com/gitent/doc/GitEnterprise/Auditing.html

Hope this helps.

Luca.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see why not, they both can be configure to send and receive data via the same protocol (SSH).

Comment: because git allows users to rewrite history, which is a common workflow in rebasing and squashing. Additional users can blame/credit commits under any email they like.  SVN uses (by default) hooks to disable history changes (revprops) and ties each commit to the authenticated user.